# Prevent UITableView rows from being destroyed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a large UITableView and I need to iterate through its cell to extract some information. The problem is that the cells which outside the UITableView bounds are equal null, so I cannot extract any information about them.

Is it possible to prevent UITableView from destroying the cells that are out of bounds (current invisible cells). Modifying the datasource and reloading the whole table is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy all the cells you create into a NSMutableArray and keep a reference of them there, in that way the system won't release them, but this is not the way you should work with it.

This can lead to big memory issues if your table is too long, you should think in a solution that saves the data of the cell, not the cell itself.

Comment: The answer is correct, however please pay attention to the second part - it is very important as your app will be crashing because of memory issues with such solution. Avoid this pattern.

Comment: I had the same thoughts, but needed someone to stop me of doing bad things. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, but you don't want to do that. I mean really! You don't!!

The question is why you need this kind of behaviour, you should be fine using just data source and maybe row count. If you want information about 'invisible cells' you really should look at your `NSArray`/`CoreData` or whatever it is what fill your TableView

Answer (score 0):

You have to reconsider your approach. Cells consumes a lot of resources so they are usually made reusable - so you don't have to keep them all in memory or destroy/create for each new row. You should have all your data in some array (you can save to array from core data or from web service or whatever). Then, to get any data refer to indexpath.row from your array (objectAtIndex:indexpath.row).

Answer (score 0):

You can use embedded `UITableView` in a `UIScrollView` to prevent destroying cells.

This works by telling UITableView to reset its content size to the full height.

But with the following conditions:

1. Disable scrolling of UITableView.
2. Subclass UITableView with the following class and use it in code/storyboard:

   ```
   class IntrinsicTableView: UITableView {

    override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }
   }
   ```